# change iPhone tableview cell label text on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uilabel, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I want to change text of custom UITableviewCell text on didSelectRowAtIndexPath and I am using following code:-

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.lblName.text=@"cambridge";
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

 }
```

but I am getting "**request for member 'levelNo' in something not a structure or union**". However I am able to set it at cellForRowAtIndexPath.
***Please help***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 YourCustomCell *cell = (YourCustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.lblName.text=@"cambridge";
 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

 //update your data, your data source must be mutable
 //in case your array content are NSString, just do
  [yourMutableArrayDataSource replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"cambridge"];

 //or if your data array holds NSDictionary. you can just initialize new dictionary 
 //as a replacement of the object in case you dont want your dictionary to be mutable
 NSDictionary *tempDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"cambridge",@"text",@"yourOtherData",@"otherData" nil];
  [yourMutableArrayDataSource replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:tempDict];

 }
```

as mentioned by ***Maulik*** (thank you), the lblName text will change back to its original text when the cell scrolls. you might want to update your data source to keep the new data. **answer edited

Answer (score 0):

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.lblName.text=@"New text Here";
 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
 [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
 YourCustomCell *cell = (YourCustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.lblName.text=@"cambridge";
 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

By above code of ***janusfidel*** , label's text will be changed. But when you scroll the table , I guess value will be changed to original value.

You also need to update your data source(that is your array ) when you want to change original data.